# facebook like button red error

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I embed Facebook like button in my page, but the problem is that, when I login using the like button then the page is liked. But if I already logged in from another page or tab and I clicked the like button a red error is displayed and a message pops up that the message has been blocked by our security system.

My code to embed like button:

```html
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <head>
        <title>Facebook Checker</title>

        <script>
            (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div id="fb-root"></div>

        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.google.com" data-width="450" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am doing this on localhost when i put code in jsfiddle then a conform link is appears.

Comment: Facebook Like detect suspecious Activity on Localhost. Make a forward account and forward your localy site and past the above code its Works Fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook Like detect suspecious Activity on Localhost. Make a forward account and forward your localy site and past the above code its Works Fine :)

```
 <html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
    <title>Facebook Checker</title>

    <script>
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
</head>
     <body >
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.google.com" data-width="450" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```